# Throwing an error in map does not prevent the consecutive map to be executed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

In my angular app I have the following Login method:

```
login(username, password): Observable<User> {
  let data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append('username', username);
  data.append('password', password);
  const url = 'https://server.com/some-endpoint/';
  return this.http.post(url, data)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(json => throwUnlessLoginSuccessful('properties', json))
    .map(json => new User().deserialize(json));
}
```

So I want to do the following with the response:

1. Convert the response to JSON
2. Inspect the JSON and check for the proper response code and throw an error.
3. If this all works parse the json into my user object.

This is my `throwUnlessLoginSuccessful` method:

```
private throwUnlessLoginSuccessful(string: string, json: Object) {

  if (Number(json["responseCode"]) > 0) {
    console.warn("Sign in failed");
    return Observable.throw(new Error(json['responseCodeMessage']));
  }
     return json;
}
```

This is how I use the login service from my UI:

```
this.loginService.login(this.login.username, this.login.password).subscribe(
  user => {
    this.session.login(this.login.username);
    console.log(`Signed in with ${user.username}`);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
  },
  err => {
    console.log(`Sign in failed $\{err}`)
    this.loading.dismiss();
    console.log(err);
  },
  () => console.log('Completed')
);
```

#### The result

1. I sign in with a wrong username and I get the error "Sign in failed" as expected. Curiously the "Completed" message is not shown.
2. Now if I sign in again with a wrong username the app crashes and I get an error that the `username` is not available.

Why is "Completed" not executed the first time and why is the behaviour different if I repeat the login with the wrong credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `throw new Error(...)` instead of returning `Observable.throw(new Error(...))`. Currently you just mapped bad result to `Observable`.

Comment: Any idea, why the "Completed" message is not logged?

Comment: It looks like onError and onComplete are mutually exclusive. See http://paqmind.com/posts/rxjs-error-and-completed-events-demystified/

Comment: actually it does, mapping value to observable is pointless, it should be flatMap at least.